# audio mapping in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a video file with audio in only one channel, left.

I'd like to use the ffmpeg `-map_channel` option to map that audio so that it appears in both the L&R channels.

what would the ffmpeg command for that look like?

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mov -c:v copy -c:a copy -map_channel 0.1.0 -map_channel 0.1.0 OUTPUT.mov
```

isn't working. The audio is still in the left channel only.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `-c:a copy`. `-map_channel` is just another way of using the [pan filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan), but you can't [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (`-c:a copy`) and filter at the same time.

If you want to use pan instead:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "pan=stereo|FL=c0:FR=c0" -c:v copy output
```

Comment: I thought `-c:a copy` would just make sure that the audio codec wasn't changed? I don't want to do anything to the video or audio except map the channel over. Thanks!

Comment: @Blake `-c:a copy` will just re-mux the audio. Think of it like a copy and paste. `-map_channel`/pan is a filter. Filters require re-encoding, so filtering and stream copying are mutually exclusive. So your command was ignoring `-map_channel` due to the presence of `-c:a copy`.

Comment: Ah. Ok. So the filter will keep the same codec unless I specify otherwise?

Comment: It will choose an appropriate audio format depending on 1): whatever output container you choose, and 2) the available encoders supported by your `ffmpeg`. For MOV it will choose AAC audio, but I can't guess what AAC encoder it will use because you did not provide the complete console output from your command.

Comment: I see. Yes it did choose AAC, but my input file is PCM. I'd like it to keep the same audio codecs, bit rates, etc. Do I have to specify all of that when I use `-map_channel`?

Comment: @Blake If you don't want the default then you'll have to specify the encoder, such as `-c:a pcm_s16le`. You don't need to specify bitrate with PCM.